# How to clear route parameter in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a master detail view in my angular application.

The main url is /blog.  If a user goes to /blog/slug then it goes to the same component but selects that post like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty('slug') && params['slug'] != '') {
            this.selectedPost = this.posts.find(x => x.slug == params['slug']);

        }
    });
}
```

The user can get to another post when then they click on it's link in the master view:

```
onSelect(post: Post): void {
    this.selectedPost = post;
}
```

I also have a list that the user can filter the topics by.   What I would like to do is to clear the selectedPost and also remove the slug parameter from the URL when the filter is changed.

I can clear the selected post like so:

```
changeTopic(topic: Topic) {
    this.selectedPost = null;

}
```

Now how do I reset the URL back to /blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the Router into the master component. If you have a route configured for the path `/blog`, invoke `router.navigate('/blog');`